# Destroying session on completing order?

Tags: php, event-observer, model, session

I am working on an extension and i want to destroy specific customly created session when the order is placed, not when it's paid, but just when it is created.

Here is my config code:

```
<global>
..... 
<events>
<sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
        <clear_session>
            <class>PercentPayment_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>clearCheckoutSession</method>
        </clear_session>
    </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
 .....
</global>
```

And here is my observer: /app/code/local/VivasIndustries/PercentPayment/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?PHP
class VivasIndustries_PercentPayment_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{

    public function clearCheckoutSession()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPcPayment(); // Or whatever you want to clear
    }

}
```

Here is my complete config.xml: http://pastebin.com/YEyBJiPY please check it out.

The problem is that the session is not destroyed when the order is created.
Where is my mistake, can you help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the observer is actually triggered? To unset a session just set it as NULL: `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPcPayment(null);`

Comment: Lex, because this is so closely related to your other question, you should consider referencing it here, or maybe closing one question and revising the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try :
change

```
<class>PercentPayment_Model_Observer</class>
```

to :

```
<class>percentpayment/observer</class>
```

Comment: While this is preferred, it should have no impact on Magento's ability to create an instance. See `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelClassName`.

Comment: @RickBuczynski you are correct here but the full path seems to be a typo also which could be causing the issue.